# expected value of a game

Tags: probability

I am watching a youtube video where it explains the expected value. [image]

I can follow alone except that red negative 1 and its probability is 1?
[image]

Why do we need to add them into our expect value? 
Here is the [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAjVAEDil_Q)

Why is this example different than expected value of the fair dice where we can just add them up as: E(x)=(1/6)*1+(1/6)*2+(1/6)*3+(1/6)*4+(1/6)*5+(1/6)*6, which is 3.5. 
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ denotes what comes in then $\mathbb EX=\frac12\cdot0+\frac18\cdot1+\frac14\cdot2+\frac18\cdot10$.

But I expect something goes out too. You must probably pay $1$ dollar (for certain) to join the game.

That means that we are more interested $X-1$ and $\mathbb E(X-1)=\mathbb EX-1$.

In my view it is not correct to look at $-1$ as an outcome.

Comment: I  see. if the fair dice game also costs 2 dollars to and reward the amount of dollars according on the number of dot on the dice. Then the "expected value" of this fair dice game is E(x)=(1/6)*1+(1/6)*2+(1/6)*3+(1/6)*4+(1/6)*5+(1/6)*6-2.  Can you please explain a bit more what you mean by "it is not correct to look at −1−1 as an outcome." Thank you.

Comment: The fact that you must pay 1 dollar to join the game is not the outcome of some experiment that has a probabilistic character. Also the summation of all probabilities of outcomes must be 1.

Answer (score 1):

@drhab has the right answer and here is another way you can look at this: If you agree to pay a dollar to play the game then after the game has ended you will have

- $0-1=-1$ with probability $1/2$
- $1-1=0$ with probability $1/8$
- $2-1=1$ with probability $1/4$
- $10-1=9$ with probability $1/8$

Note that in each scenario you will have paid the dollar, so the probability of having to pay the dollar is $1/2+1/8+1/4+1/8=1.$

The way this is presented in the video is very misleading, though, since having to pay the dollar is not an outcome of the wheel of fortune itself.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of a game is basically means the average gain of the game if you plays it a lot of times. For example fair cube let's say I played 7000 times and the sum of the results is ~24500 now the average is $\sim\frac{24500}{700}=\sim3.5$ now let say it cost me $1$ to play with the cube, so my gain after those 700 games will be ~24500-700, let's calculate the average of this: $\sim\frac{24500}{700}-\frac{700}{700}=\sim3.5-1=\sim2.5$

For this it is easy to see that the expected value of a game that cost money to play is the expected value of the game without the cost(this part is also called the value of the game) minus the cost.

Now what I said about the way to calculate the value of the game is exactly the same like the way you so of the video:

By the law of big numbers this value can be calculate by the weighted average of the game possible results(this is how the video done it).

Now to get the expected value just do minus the cost, in your case you will have the expected value=$\overbrace{\frac12\cdot0+\frac18\cdot1+\frac14\cdot2+\frac18\cdot10}^{\text{the value of the game}}-\overbrace{1}^{\text{the cost}}$

Comment: hi @Holo, so just would like to clarify a bit more: you meant that  when we are calculating the expected value, we don't need to minus the cost to play it (in the case of playing game). Thank you.

Comment: @user3096996 at first you ignore the cost and after you calculate the expected value without the cost you subtract the cost from the result